# Android: spinner in alertdialog crashed

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I have spinner in alertdialog. If alertdialog is showing and screen orientation is changed - everything OK. Alertdialog still showing. But if spinner is open and screen orientation is changed, then app crashed with View not attached to window manager. I tried alertdialog.dismiss() in onDestroy, but unsuccessful. Any ideas?

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ScrollingActivity.this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(ScrollingActivity.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);

alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.def_recipe_lang);
alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_language_orange_24px);
// create alert dialog
alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

---

Error:
    09-23 15:06:27.745 15519-15519/com.example.user.coordinatortest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:385)
                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:287)
                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
                                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:323)
                                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:306)
                                                                                      at android.widget.Spinner$DialogPopup.dismiss(Spinner.java:840)
                                                                                      at android.widget.Spinner.onDetachedFromWindow(Spinner.java:414)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onDetachedFromWindow(AppCompatSpinner.java:399)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12024)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2612)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2610)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2610)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2610)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2610)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2610)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2610)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2610)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2950)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:4535)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3318)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Did you try debugging through your code or looking at logcat?

Comment: pls post your code atleast for alert box

Answer (score 1):

"I tried alertdialog.dismiss() in onDestroy", ---- This was right but you have to do it in Onpause() not in the Ondestroy().

Ondestroy will be executed on the destruction of the screen, not on the orientation change.

Try this and if you got an error, post your code and android monitor error for an appropriate answer.

Comment: onPause also does not help. Livecycle for orientation change is: onSaveInstanceState
onPause
onStop
onDestroy
onCreate
onStart
onRestoreInstanceState
onResume     .